# image sizes for responsibility web Site

Tags: web, web-deployment, visual-web-developer

How I can choose image sizes for multiple screen's size for responsibility on all devices?

Comment: You should read [this](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)

Answer (score 0):

[PictureFill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) is a great responsive image polyfill.

It's nice and simple to use. Just add the following line to your site's `<head>`:

```
<script>
    // Picture element HTML5 shiv
    document.createElement( "picture" );
</script>
<script src="picturefill.js" async></script>
```

Create your images as required (dependent on your target devices or screen sizes). And add them using the following script:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="images/large-kitten.jpg" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
    <source srcset="images/medium-kitten.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <img srcset="images/fallback-kitten.jpg" alt="Kitten">
</picture>
```

There are some downsides, such as:

- JS-Disabled Browsers will only see `alt` text.
- Temporary extra HTTP requests are sent for `picture` usage in some browsers.
- Source element limitations
- Media attribute support requires native media query support.

Alternatively, add a fair sized image and use the following CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```